# How to chain two counter functions so they occur sequentially using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, chaining

I would like to run two functions sequentially, such that the first function runs, and then the second function runs after. Usually I can do this by simply calling the first function first and use it's result for the second function

See below for my code and here for my [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OEKNqM?editors=1010)

```
function add_count(i){
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = i
}

function count_three_up(i){
  setTimeout(add_count,1000,i)
  setTimeout(add_count,2000,i+1)
  setTimeout(add_count,3000,i+2)
  return i + 3
}

next_number = count_three_up(1)//first function
count_three_up(next_number)//second function
```

The result of this produces:

```
1, 4, 3, 5, 3, 6
```

However I'd like to produce

```
 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I should mention that it's important that the second function uses the result from the first function.

Comment: It sounds like you simply want to count up once per second. The entire question sounds extremely like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), can you tell us what your actual goal is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take different value to add, because you have different times for timeout.

What you have is

```
time   1000  2000  3000
values    1     2     3
          4     5     6
```

but you need

```
time   1000  2000  3000
values    1     3     5
          2     4     6
```

That means, you need to return only a value incremented by one instead of three.

```js
function add_count(i){
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = i;
}

function count_three_up(i){
    setTimeout(add_count, 1000, i);
    setTimeout(add_count, 2000, i + 2);
    setTimeout(add_count, 3000, i + 4);
    return i + 1;
}

next_number = count_three_up(1);
count_three_up(next_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_count(i){
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = i
}

function count_three_up(i, callback){
    var iteration = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        add_count(i);
        i++;
        iteration++;
        if(iteration === 3) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            if(callback)callback();
        }
    }, 1000);

    return i + 3
}

var next_number = count_three_up(1, function(){
    count_three_up(next_number)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpreted your question as: "I want to show consecutive numbers one by one with a delay in between each number".

Use a local method and call it in `setTimeout`as long as an intermediate array of values is not empty

```js
const result = document.querySelector("#result");
const write = (v, atStart) => result.textContent += `${(atStart ? "" : ",")}${v}`;
const createCounterArray = max => Array.from({length: max}).map( (v, i) => i + 1 );
showConsecutiveNumbersDelayed(createCounterArray(6), 1).write();

function showConsecutiveNumbersDelayed(arr, delay = 0.2) {
  const len = arr.length - 1;
  const doWrite = () => 
    arr.length && setTimeout(doWrite, delay * 1000) && write(arr.shift(), arr.length === len);
  return {write: doWrite};
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the timeouts as `1000`, `2000`, `3000`, `1000`, `2000` ... instead you might want to make it dependent on i:

```
function count_three_up(i){
  setTimeout(add_count, 1000 * i , i)
  setTimeout(add_count, 1000 * (i + 1), i+1)
  setTimeout(add_count, 1000 * (i + 2), i+2)
  return i + 3
}
```

---

While that works, it might be more elegant to solve the whole thing with promises:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function countUp(start, up = 3) {
  for(let i = start, i < start + up; i++) {
    await delay(1000);
    add_count(i);
  }
  return start + up;
}
```

So then you can do:

```
countUp(0, 3).then(countUp);
```